# recerence_id from belongs_to doesn't update on destroy its parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that has self belongs_to:

```
class SyncType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sync_type, touch: true
  has_many :sync_types, -> { order('created_at ASC') }
end
```

and I saved 2 objets on database:

```
 #<SyncType id: 99, description: "test", sync_type_id: nil, created_at: "2014-07-16 18:49:09", updated_at: "2014-07-16 18:49:09">
 #<SyncType id: 95, description: "haha", sync_type_id: 99, created_at: "2014-07-16 18:31:48", updated_at: "2014-07-16 18:31:48">
```

So, I need to fetch all SyncTypes that don't have parent for my business:

```
@sync_types_tree = SyncType.where("sync_type_id is null")
```

but when I destroy the object with id 99 its reference doesn't update on the object with id 95 (sync_type_id: 99). What can I do to refresh it? I would like to put sync_type_id: nil when I destroy it.

According to the rails guide, the "touch: true," this would work but it isn't.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#touch

My temp solution:

```
@sync_types_to_destroy.each do |sync_to_destroy|
  sync_to_destroy.sync_types.each do |child|
    child.sync_type = nil
    child.save
  end
  sync_to_destroy.destroy
end
```

if you have a better idea, please help me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the :dependent option on the has_many association:

```
has_many :sync_types, -> { order('created_at ASC') }, dependent: :nullify
```

Now when you destroy the parent record, the children will get their sync_type_id attributes nullified.

```
sync_type = SyncType.where("sync_type_id is null").first
sync_type.destroy
```

Using your example records, the following SQL is executed:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE `sync_types` SET `sync_types`.`sync_type_id` = NULL WHERE `sync_types`.`sync_type_id` = 99 ORDER BY created_at ASC;
DELETE FROM `sync_types` WHERE `sync_types`.`id` = 99;
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a before_destroy callback that removes the links on the other records.

```
class SyncType < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :remove_links

  private 
  def remove_links
    SyncType.where('sync_type_id = ?', id).update_all(sync_type_id: nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for help but the answer above helps me!